# VueJS parent communication to child element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

New to VueJS so hoping to get some advice on the best approach to take.

I have a parent containing multiple child components.

Once the child components have been created there is an event handler attached to each child

```
this.$parent.$on('save', this.save);
```

So that whenever I emit the following in the parent we call the child save method

```
this.$emit('save', block);
```

The problem that I'm seeing is that every child listen to events from this parent is reacting to this event.

Is there a better way to get a specific child to react to a parent click event?

Comment: I'd say you probably need to reconsider your design. Usually parent-child interactions are the other way around. Here's the section of docs about basics of component composition: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try passing a prop with .sync modifier to a child, and then in the child component you should use computed property. This is an option but I don't know what are you trying to achieve, is there any specific reason that you must emit an event?

Read the vue.js dosumentation for props: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

Answer (score 1):

For what you are attempting, if possible, I'd use a [Child Component `ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs) and call a method on the child from the parent:

```js
Vue.component('my-comp', {
  template: "#my-comp-template",
  props: ['name'],
  methods: {
    saveMyComp() {
      console.log('Saved:', this.name);
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    people: [{name: 'Bob'}, {name: 'Nelson'}, {name: 'Zed'}]
  },
  methods: {
    saveChild(index) {
      this.$refs.myComps[index].saveMyComp();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(person, index) in people">
    <button @click="saveChild(index)">saveMyComp</button>
    <my-comp :name="person.name" ref="myComps"></my-comp>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="my-comp-template">
    <span> {{ name }} </span>
</template>
```

Remember the parent is already coupled to the child component -- since it knows it exists in the template declaration.